# Cannot import Cython module

Tags: python, cython

I followed the Basic Tutorial from the **Cython** documentation page. I created a `helloworld.pyx` and `setup.py` file, then build. The build created `helloworld.cpython-39.so` but when I tried to `import helloworld`, I got the following error. How can I fix this?

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen failed: library "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/temp/helloworld.cpython-39.so" needed or dlopened by "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" is not accessible for the namespace "(default)"
>>>
```

Comment: do you have read permission on the file ? try giving your user a read permission on it.

Comment: it is already rw 
-rw-rw----    1 root     everybod    104388 Oct 26 18:40 helloworld.c
-rw-rw----    1 root     everybod     19888 Oct 26 18:40 helloworld.cpython-39.so

Comment: I'm not sure if Cython is supported on android. It certainly isn't tested on android.